# How to debug $.ajax not ending call

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I have a $.ajax call to upload an image to a php server, running on chrome, on an iphone.

This task, when tested on an iphone, have some none ending
upload task.  I started to call some alert on .done(), .fail(),
but nothing tells me what happen.  The $.ajax keeps running, as 
showed by the iphone spinning wheel and I witness the file not being uploaded.

What variables, settings should I look for to get more information 
on this none ending loop on the iphone dev?

Answer (score 1):

You can debug the web content on iphone using safari or chrome:

safari: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

chrome: http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/debugging-javascript-ios-mosync-reload